# Blender bones not effecting the mesh correctly

Tags: rigging, bones, vertex-weights

I made a gun for my character, I tried to add a `Hand Holder` bone to my character rig to be able to move the gun as the characters hand moves.
[image: picture of hand holder bone]
And I parented it in a way that the `Hand Holder` bone was effecting the gun 100%. but the problem is that the gun mesh is not in the `Hand Holder`s position and it has some offsets :[image: Image of my blend file]

I researched google for any answer but the only thing I found is by changing the weight of the bones which doesn't worked.

I tried doing weight painting and resetting the position of the gun, and none of them worked for me.

blend file : [image]

Comment: do you want it like that? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9kAX.gif

Comment: Exactly like that @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. delete the parent and the armature modifier of your gun

[image]

2. select your gun in object mode
3. shift select the armature of your man, go to pose mode and select this bone

[image]

4. CTRL P -> Bone

[image]

5. go back to object mode and rotate/move your bone that it fits in hand

result:

[image]